# Samsung Galaxy S4 S Planner events have different timezones

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, time-zones

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4

In the S Planner, the events have two time zones in their Detail view; e.g. GMT+3 and UTC.

I would only like to see only my local time zone. Is there a setting for that? Couldn't find anything on the web. The time zones are set to manual both in the phone and in the app.

Answer (score 1):

The `Lock time zone` setting in the S Planner says:

> Lock event times and dates to your selected time zone below. Times and
>   dates will not change even if you move to another time zone.

This means that the event retains the same timezone it was originally created with. However, the display will be adjusted according to the locked timezone.

e.g. If you were originally in GMT+3, and you created an event using GMT+3 at 10:00, and then locked the timezone at GMT+4, then you will see that the time has changed to GMT+4 11:00 to reflect the selected timezone. Internally, this is still GMT+3 10:00.

New events that you create will be based on the locked timezone.